# Simple Accordion Targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am having an issue with figuring out how to target a certain item in my website design using JavaScript.

I am creating a simple accordion:

```
    $(function($) {
        var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
        $('.accordion > dd:nth-child(2)').show();
        $('.accordion > dt > a').on('click', function() {
            allPanels.slideUp('fast');
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown('fast');
        return false;
        });
    });
```

What I would prefer to do is, instead of telling the ".next()" to slide down, i want to target one of my tags "4 tags away," much like an nth child, but by measuring from the clicked tag. This is my html code, to clarify:

```
    <dl class="accordion">
        <dt><a href="">Linked element 1</a></dt>
        <dt><a href="">Linked element 2</a></dt>
        <dt><a href="">Linked element 3</a></dt>
        <dt><a href="">Linked element 4</a></dt>
        <dd>Linked element 1 - dropdown content</dd>
        <dd>Linked element 2 - dropdown content</dd>
        <dd>Linked element 3 - dropdown content</dd>
        <dd>Linked element 4 - dropdown content</dd>
    </dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
$('.accordion > dd:eq(1)').show();
$('.accordion > dt > a').on('click', function () {
    allPanels.slideUp('fast');
    $('.accordion dd').eq($('.accordion dt a').index(this)).slideDown('fast');
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MuRG3/1/)**

Comment: This works perfectly as an independent function, but given that the list I am using in my html is among a full page utilizing the anchor tag for other elements (ie. navigation in the header) the ".eq($('a')." portion is not working correctly. Apologies for not clarifying that there was other content on the page.

Comment: Excellent! I thank you greatly; I only have base syntax knowledge from actionscript so JS is just a little out of my reach at the moment.